# Quantum Ripple Carry Adder Construction

Tags: universal-gates, gate-synthesis, quantum-gate

There is an excellent [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/how-do-i-add-11-using-a-quantum-computer/1656) to [How do I add 1+1 using a quantum computer?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/how-do-i-add-11-using-a-quantum-computer/1656) that shows constructions of the half and full adders. In the answer, there is a source for the [QRCA](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0410184v1). I have also looked at [this presentation](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/presentation/4758/ba24724e378caad94ab1d083ab8392df9e48.pdf).

I am still left with these questions:

1. What does a truth table for a QRCA look like?
2. What would a unitary matrix for a QRCA be?
3. What would a circuit diagram for a QRCA look like? (There is an example of a 6-bit circuit in the arXiv paper)

Comment: You acknowledge that there's a quantum circuit diagram for a particular size in the paper you're citing. What more are you after regarding quantum circuits?

Comment: Here's the abstract: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-85194-3_19

Comment: also, the first two lines of figure 5 effectively define the truth table, from which you can directly derive the unitary matrix.

Comment: Again, apologies. I do not actually know how to derive the matrix from the table (or how to dervive a truth table for a quantum gate). Nor am I able to create circuits (the 6-bit circuit is more complex than a 2 or 3 bit circuit). Obviously very new to logic cicuits & quantum computing!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What does a truth table for a QRCA look like?

You don't want to know. It will be a gigantic complicated table that provides no insight whatsoever. At the very least you need to use boolean algebra instead of a table, but even that will be cumbersome and will require many intermediate values that ultimately are just a less-visual way of describing an addition circuit.

If it helps, here is the set of equations for a simpler operation, an increment operation. The equations define how each output bit can be computed from the input bits:

$o_0 = i_0 \oplus 1$

$o_1 = i_1 \oplus i_0$

$o_2 = i_2 \oplus (i_0 \land i_1)$

$\vdots$

$o_n = i_n \oplus {\Large{\land}}_{k=0}^{n-1} i_k$

> What would a unitary matrix for a QRCA be?

It's a permutation matrix.

As a starting point, here is the permutation matrix corresponding to a 2-bit increment:

$$\text{Inc}_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
&&&1\\
1&&&\\
&1&&\\
&&1&\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

and a 3-bit increment:

$$\text{Inc}_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
&&&&&&&1\\
1&&&&&&&\\
&1&&&&&&\\
&&1&&&&&\\
&&&1&&&&\\
&&&&1&&&\\
&&&&&1&&\\
&&&&&&1&\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

I suspect you see the pattern. Just start with an identity matrix and shift it down by 1 (with the bottom row wrapping around to the top). To add 2, instead of adding 1 (i.e. incrementing) you would just shift down by 2 instead of by 1.

In an addition circuit, the amount of shifting depends on the other input. So you end up with a series of sub-matrices with increasingly-shifted diagonals:

$$\text{Add}_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&&&\\
&1&&\\
&&1&\\
&&&1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\\&
\begin{bmatrix}
&&&1\\
1&&&\\
&1&&\\
&&1&\\
\end{bmatrix}
\\&&
\begin{bmatrix}
&&1&\\
&&&1\\
1&&&\\
&1&&\\
\end{bmatrix}
\\&&&
\begin{bmatrix}
&1&&\\
&&1&\\
&&&1\\
1&&&\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}$$

> What would a circuit diagram for a QRCA look like?

There are many possible constructions. [Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.07884) is one that works entirely inline:

[image: addition circuit]

You can [play with this construction in Quirk](http://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22Counting5%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22Chance5%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Chance5%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C%22X%22%2C%22X%22%2C%22X%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%2C%22X%22%2C%22X%22%2C%22X%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22X%22%2C%22X%22%2C%22X%22%2C%22X%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%2C%22X%22%2C%22X%22%2C%22X%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22Chance5%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Chance5%22%5D%5D%7D).