# How to add two integers in Q#?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, programming, q#

I have programmed in C++, but I am interested in writing quantum programs. I have some experience with Microsoft's Q#, and I know about the canonical Shor's and Grover's algorithms.

Can anyone tell me how to write a quantum program to add two integers?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to QuantumComputing.SE. We prefer questions, where some effort has been done already. Please show us what you have already tried or searched for.

Comment: See: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1654/2645 & https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2346/2645

Comment: The title for your question was "writing a program in Q#" but your question's body asks how to add two integers, so I've changed your title. Now you're at risk of having the article marked as a duplicate, because people have asked how to add 1+1 in Q# before.

Answer (score 4):

You will need quantum circuits called adders.

You have for example one from [Cuccaro *et al.*](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fpdf%2Fquant-ph%2F0410184.pdf) and another from [Himanshu *et al.*](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fpdf%2F1712.02630.pdf)

Comment: Are these different from adders as implemented on a reversible classical computer?

Comment: I do not know how those are implemented on reversible classical computers (generally not considered) but it is possible that it was the inspiration. They adapt in quantum operations the addition bit-wise but trying to minimize the number of extra qubits and the complexity of the circuit. As the circuit is unitary, you can apply this with superposition.

Comment: There are also some links to adders in the Q# online documentation on https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/quantum-formoreinfo.