# How to simulate a simple circuit to add two numbers in Quirk?

Tags: circuit-construction, quirk

I am new and I don't understand where I should give the input and where I should get the output. Please explain with an example of a circuit run on the Quirk simulator. How to add two numbers?

Comment: **Related**: [How do I add 1+1 using a quantum computer?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1654)

Comment: Check out this video tutorial by Craig Gidney: [How to use Quirk - Toy Quantum Circuit Simulator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aloFwlBUwsQ).