# How do I add 1+1 using a photonic computer?

Tags: circuit-construction, mathematics, photonics

A [similar question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/how-do-i-add-11-using-a-quantum-computer) has been previously asked & has an [excellent answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/1656/2645) discussing half, full & ripple carry adders. I am curious to find out how these adders would be constructed in the setting of photonic quantum computers (eg. with continuous variable qumodes instead of qubits).

Comment: Are you asking for a practical addition algorithm, such as the ones that classical computers and humans use? Or is simply counting up acceptable?