# How does quantum computer store data in QPU and how to calculate?

Tags: quantum-state

I couldn't understand any popular science books and articles about quantum mechanisms. And that's why I post here to find an answer to my years-long confusion.

Popular science articles tell us that a qubit could represent both 1 and 0 at a time. So, it raised a question in my mind: how could the QPU perform a calculation?

For example, if I need to calculate `1+0=?`, there should be a `qubit1=1` and a `qubit2=0`, and then, `qubit3` to store the result of the calculation. However, as the articles told us, qubit1 and qubit2 may be both 1 and 0 separately. So, eventually, will the result of the calculation be 0, 1, or 2? How could the computer determine the value of an uncertain qubit?

Comment: Welcome to QCSE.  Have you reviewed this [question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/how-do-i-add-11-using-a-quantum-computer) and the answers provided therein?

Comment: The OP may correct me if I am wrong, but it seems to me they are not asking about addition specifically, but in understanding quantum calculations generally. This is at any rate what I tried to address in my answer. ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###### How to define a quantum calculation

We say quantum operations are *linear*, meaning they can be defined by their action on individual basis states (ie. each qubit is *either* 0 *or* 1).

For example, an ${\rm XOR}$ operator acting on two input qubits and an output qubit may be defined as following:

$$
{\rm XOR} \left[|00⟩|0⟩\right] = |00⟩|0⟩ \\
{\rm XOR} \left[|01⟩|0⟩\right] = |01⟩|1⟩ \\
{\rm XOR} \left[|10⟩|0⟩\right] = |10⟩|1⟩ \\
{\rm XOR} \left[|11⟩|0⟩\right] = |11⟩|0⟩
$$
(This covers the usual cases when your output qubit starts at as 0. You'll also need to define actions on $|x_1 x_2⟩|1⟩$ such that the $\rm XOR$ operation is *reversible*, but I think that's beyond the scope of your question.)

In order to actually get information out of the quantum operation, you need to *measure* the output qubit. As long as your input qubits are in a basis state (ie. each qubit is *either* 0 or 1), measuring the output qubit will always give *either* 0 *or* 1.

###### Considering superposition

Now let's consider the case when the input qubits are taking advantage of their quantum nature and they are representing *both* 0 *and* 1 at the same time; ie. they are in a quantum *superposition*.

For example, say $|ψ_{\rm in}⟩ = a|00⟩ + b|01⟩ + c|10⟩ + d|11⟩$. Because the $\rm XOR$ operator is *linear*, we simply apply ${\rm XOR}$ to each individual term and add up the result:

$$ {\rm XOR}\left[|ψ_{\rm in}⟩|0⟩\right] = \left[ a|00⟩ + d|11⟩ \right] |0⟩ + \left[ b|01⟩ + c|10⟩ \right] |1⟩ $$

Now the output qubit is in a superposition (in fact it is *entangled* with the input qubits, but that doesn't actually matter at the moment). When you measure it, you may get *both* 0 *and* 1. That is, any single measurement will only ever give one or the other, but repeat the experiment many times and you'll get a mix. Most quantum algorithms are interested in this mixture, rather than the result (0 or 1) from a single experiment.

Precisely what mixture you get depends on the numerical values of $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$. You could calculate it ahead of time, but I suppose you might say the point of quantum computing is that we don't have to. ^_^

###### Note on addition

I used ${\rm XOR}$ (aka. *binary* addition) as my example here because its output is always 0 or 1, so that we would only need one output qubit. In "normal" additon, adding two bits may give 0, 1, or 2. Even classically, you can't put 2 into a single bit..! The solution is to add a second output bit, usually called the *carry* bit. Please check out the question linked in @Mark S's comment for more details on a quantum implementation.