# What is the unitary matrix for a full adder?

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction

I need the unitary matrix for a full adder.
I want to assess how an automatically generated circuit is close to the full adder. Therefore,I need a unitary matrix for the full adder. I believe it should be $2^5 \times 2^5$ (two inputs, two outputs and one carry out).
Does anyone have this unitary matrix for the full adder?

Comment: Welcome to QCSE.  Your question seems similar to [this one](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/how-do-i-add-11-using-a-quantum-computer).  Or are you asking more about converting an arbitrary truth table specifically into a unitary matrix?

Comment: Also, please try to avoid postings that use phrases like "I need", as it sounds demanding of volunteers' time.  I recommend you edit your posting by clicking on the button next to "Share", to remove the words "I need", and replace them with "I would like".   Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A full adder is usually depicted like this, with 1-bit inputs, sum, and carry:

[image]

A simple quantum circuit for the corresponding truth table could be drawn like this:

[image]

In my own code base, this translates into [this](https://github.com/qcc4cp/qcc/blob/a5d07cdc632b4393445d9416c4368b08124f02cb/src/arith_classic.py#L37) code:

```
  psi = ops.Cnot(0, 3)(psi, 0)
  psi = ops.Cnot(1, 3)(psi, 1)
  psi = ops.ControlledU(0, 1, ops.Cnot(1, 4))(psi, 0)
  psi = ops.ControlledU(0, 2, ops.Cnot(2, 4))(psi, 0)
  psi = ops.ControlledU(1, 2, ops.Cnot(2, 4))(psi, 1)
  psi = ops.Cnot(2, 3)(psi, 2)
  return psi
```

This code applies the gates one after the other. So in order to obtain a single big matrix you have to multiply all the gates together in reverse order and properly pad them to 5 qubits, as in the following (assuming I didn't make a mistake here), where `*` denotes the Kronecker product and `@` is matrix multiply:

```
  M = ((ops.Identity(2) * ops.Cnot(2, 3) * ops.Identity(1)) @
       (ops.Identity(1) * ops.ControlledU(1, 2, ops.Cnot(2, 4))) @
       (ops.ControlledU(0, 2, ops.Cnot(2, 4))) @
       (ops.ControlledU(0, 1, ops.Cnot(1, 4))) @
       (ops.Identity(1) * ops.Cnot(1, 3) * ops.Identity(1)) @
       (ops.Cnot(0, 3) * ops.Identity(1)) )
```

The resulting matrix is $2^5 \times 2^5$ and looks something like:

```
Operator for 5-qubit state space. Tensor:
[[1.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j ... 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]
 [0.+0.j 1.+0.j 0.+0.j ... 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]
 [0.+0.j 0.+0.j 1.+0.j ... 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]
 ...
 [0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j ... 0.+0.j 1.+0.j 0.+0.j]
 [0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j ... 1.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]
 [0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j ... 0.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]]
```

This should be relatively simple to achieve in other infrastructures, such as Qiskit. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

A quantum circuit for the full adder is illustrated here:

https://www.quantum-inspire.com/kbase/full-adder/

I think you can easily compute the corresponding unitary matrix.

A study on the implementation of adders is reported in the following recent article:

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=9655478

Comment: thanks, but i font know hot to get the unitary matrix from this circuit. is there any python code?